# Weak convergence (dual) in $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: functional-analysis

In $X=\mathbb{R^n}$ is the weak convergence (in the sense of the definition in Banach spaces: for every $L \in X^*, Lx_n \to  Lx$) equivalent to the strong convergence?

Comment: yes. Surely one of the first few limit theorems you learn in $\Bbb{R}^n$ is that $(x_1,\dots, x_n)\to (a_1,\dots, a_n)$ if and only if $x_i\to a_i$ in $\Bbb{R}$ for each $i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and this ultimately relies on the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n$ has finite dimension (although it's not necessary: in $\mathcal{l}^1$ weak and strong convergence are equivalent, even though it's harder to prove). One implication is trivial, so let's see that weak convergence implies strong convergence.

The dual of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is by definition the set of all linear and continuous maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The important facts here are these:

1. Every linear map can be represented by a scalar product with respect to a particular vector $v$ (this is the so called Riesz representation theorem and it's true even in Hilbert spaces, but it doesn't matter now).
2. If every component of $v_k$ converges strongly to the corresponding component of $v$, then $v_k \to v$ (it's here that you use the finite dimension!)

So, by definition, $v_k \rightharpoonup v \iff f(v_k) \to f(v)$ for every $f$ that is linear (and continuous, but this is implied by linearity). Thanks to fact 1.  we can restate that condition as:

$$v_k \rightharpoonup v \iff \langle v_k, w\rangle \to \langle v, w \rangle \text{ for every } w \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

but now it's easy, because you can consider $w=e_j$ for some $j=1, \dots, n$, and denoting $v_k= (v_k ^1, v_k ^2, \dots, v_k ^n)$ and $v= (v^1, \dots, v^n)$ you have:

$$\langle v_k , e_j \rangle = v_k ^j \to \langle v, e_j \rangle= v^j \text{ as } k \to + \infty$$

that is every component of $v_k$ converges to the corresponding component of $v$, and we're done thanks to point 2.